# appendRow from an array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

If I have an array, `[Joe, John, Adam, Sam, Bill, Bob]` and I want to try to add this to a new row by doing `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet4').appendRow([array]);` , what happens is that the entire list of names goes into 1 cell. Is there a way to break this up so they file away into the same row, but different columns? I need to continue using appendRow however.

I get this:

[image: Bad]

But I really want to have it look like this:

[image: Good]

```
 var my2DArrayFromRng = datasheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var a = my2DArrayFromRng.join().split(',').filter(Boolean);

     var array = [];

    for (d in a) {

    array.push(a[d]);

    }

SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet4').appendRow([array.toString()]);
```

Comment: Please post the full code you are using to get this result.

Comment: @Hink added as requested.

Comment: Did you try `...appendRow(array);`? If you make the array a string it will obviously be only one cell and appendRow takes a simple array, not a 2d array.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach when I do what you suggest I get in one cell [Ljava.lang.Object;@35d77835

Answer (score 1):

You are converting your array to a string before you post it which is causing your issue.

Do not use the `array.toString()` method inside append row. Instead just append the array as it is.

`SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet4').appendRow(array);`

Comment: I wrote on another comment that doing this does not return anything except  [Ljava.lang.Object;@35d77835 into the cell.

Comment: After further analysis it turns out I was doing .appendRow([new Date(), array]) which placed the array inside another array which made it look wrong. I removed the Date and made it part of the array and it is now working.